Nested Generic return Type in Spring Swagger
Very close to this question How to specify a generic type class for Swagger API response But not quite the same.
Using OpenApi v3 and Spring boot 3.3,
I have these structures:
public class BaseResponseBody<T>{
    private T result;
    private String error;
    private Object errorDetail;
}

public class BaseResponse<T> extends ResponseEntity<BaseResponseBody<T>> {
    private BaseResponse(String error, T result, HttpStatusCode status, Object errorDetail, HttpHeaders headers) {
        super(new BaseResponseBody<>(result, error, errorDetail), headers, status);
    }
...
}

Then in my controller:
@GetMapping("/wrong")
public BaseResponse<String> wrong() {
    return BaseResponse.withResultOK("");
}

and then swagger does not show the BaseResponseBody:

but if I define the method like this(Not using BaseResponse):
@GetMapping("/correct")
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponseBody<String>> correct() {
    return BaseResponse.withResultOK("");
}

swagger shows the generic types correctly:

How can I make it generate document with BaseResponseBody using BaseResponse and not having to use ResponseEntity?
